# Is Teichmüller distance bigger than Weil-Petersson distance on Teichmüller space?

Tags: moduli-spaces, teichmuller-theory, weil-petersson-metric

It is known that Teichmüller distance ($d_{Teich}$) on Teichmüller space is complete, whereas Weil-Petersson distance ($d_{WP}$) is not complete.

See for example the article

Wolpert, Scott. Noncompleteness of the Weil-Petersson metric for Teichmüller space. Pacific J. Math. 61 (1975), no. 2, 573--577
,

in which Wolpert constructs an the explicit path on the Teichmüller space, which diverges in $d_{Teich}$, but converges in $d_{WP}$.

My question is : is it true in general that there is a positive constant $C$ such that $d_{WP} < C d_{Teich}$?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, this is a [result of Michele Linch, 1974.](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~mduchin/viewing/thesis/linch-twometrics.pdf)